# I need to override a segue function after clicking a

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have this tableView and I want when clicking a cell it gives me the name of that cell, and I pass it to next view, but the problem is that I need to override segue function inside of the "didselectrowAt" function and that is impossible I guess, any suggestion on how to do this?

```
          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                  clickedYear = years[indexPath.row]
        
             }
    
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                let ResumosVC: Resumos2ViewController = segue.destination as! Resumos2ViewController
    
                ResumosVC.Title = clickedYear
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Reconnect the segue to the **cell** (rather than to the controller) and implement

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       guard let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, 
             let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
       let resumosVC = segue.destination as! Resumos2ViewController
       resumosVC.Title = years[indexPath.row]
   }
   ```
2. Call `performSegue` in `didSelect` (replace the identifier string with the real value)

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegueIdentifier", sender: indexPath)
   }
   ```

   and change `prepare(for` to

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       guard let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { return }
       let resumosVC = segue.destination as! Resumos2ViewController
       resumosVC.Title = years[indexPath.row]
   }
   ```

`clickedYear` is not needed in both cases.

Note: Please conform to the naming convention to name variables with starting lowercase letter.

Comment: Okok will do ! Sorry im a newbie but thanks for your help it worked sir!